# Why would only some characters be displayed in a Flash textbox?

Tags: c#, flash

I am wrting a program in C# that uses Flash to display a text box on a form. When I send a message to the form only some of the characters are displayed. The swf file that I'm using is from an Internet artice that explains how to send and receive data from Flash, it included source code.

Here is the funny thing. If I use the original swf file that I loaded down it works. If I take that  ela file and I rename and publish it with NO changes at all, it will only display some characters. There are no embedded fonts.

All I'm changing in the C# program is the name of the swf file.

Help!!!!

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Have you tried to compile the original FLA to the SWF with the exactly SAME name as the SWF?

Comment: Yes I have the same problem in either case.Which tells me it would be a default setting of some sort?

Comment: I am not sure which article you are referring but... but as you could try an Ajax callback and have the flash pick up on the POST variables

Comment: The artice is http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in some of the Flash fourums I found this solution http://ps3sg.blogspot.com/2011/03/adobe-flash-cs5-as2-problem-some.html. Although this seems to work, this must be a bug in Flash CS5.5

1. Click on the textbox.
2. Click on the "Embed..." button in the Character section of the Properties
3. In the Embedded Font window I selected All in the Character Ranges.
4. Click Ok.

After republishing the ela I was able to see the whole alphabet.

Gary

Comment: So the FLA indeed uses embedded characters for the dynamic text area.

Comment: I'm not sure. If nothing was checked you would think that nothing would display, but that wasn't true.

Comment: Whatever characters in that font you used elsewhere in the fla would display, even if they were in static text. To learn more check "publish size report" in your publish settings, and look at what's there.